# swipe refresh в android webview (при условии)

Tags: android, webview

здравствуйте, есть swipe refresh который перезагружает контент webview

```
        //swipe refresh
    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mywebview.loadUrl("javascript: loc = location.href; location.href=loc");

        }
    });
```

как можно дописать функцию, что если сайт находится не на главный странице , тоесть www.site.ru/ а допустим www.site.ru/test или любое другое после ".ru/" то запретить использование swipe refresh

Answer (score 3):

```
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            String currentUrl = mywebview.getUrl();
            if(!"www.site.ru".equals(currentUrl)){
               mywebview.loadUrl("javascript: loc = location.href; location.href=loc");
            }
        }
    });
```